# Saving to sharedPreferences from fragment causes InflateException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save some high scores to sharedPreferences. In my GameActivity, I created the sharedPreferences like this:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    //public static final String KEY_RESTORE = "key_restore";
    //public static final String PREFS_SCORES = "pref_scores";
    private GameFragment mGameFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        SharedPreferences highScorePreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        //final SharedPreferences highScorePreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

I then try to add my high scores list to sharedPreferences like this:

```
public class GameFragment extends Fragment {
    SharedPreferences highScorePreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE = 0;
    //private SharedPreferences highScorePreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
    private SharedPreferences.Editor highScoreEdit = highScorePreferences.edit();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (currentImage == 2) {
                    hm.addScore("Bart", score);

                    String highScoreString = hm.getHighscoreString();
                    Log.d("UT3", hm.getHighscoreString());
                    score = 0;
                    highScoreEdit.putString("high_scores", highScoreString);
                    highScoreEdit.commit();
                }
            }


        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

When I try to run the app, the GameActivity has this runtime exception: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment`

Stack Trace :

```
07-25 14:00:26.895    2024-2066/? W/PowerManagerService﹕ Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0
07-25 14:00:27.015    2139-2139/? D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController﹕ onDataActivity: direction=0
07-25 14:00:27.025    2139-2139/? D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster: data=2 bt=false
07-25 14:00:27.105    2024-2077/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.1092 ]
07-25 14:00:27.105    2024-2076/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-25 14:00:27.105    2024-2076/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-25 14:00:27.105    2024-2076/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
07-25 14:00:27.215    2024-2077/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=]
07-25 14:00:27.215    2024-2076/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
07-25 14:00:27.215    2024-2076/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
07-25 14:00:27.215    2024-2076/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
07-25 14:00:27.225    2024-2308/? I/power﹕ *** acquire_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1  freq : 1000000
07-25 14:00:27.225    2024-2308/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1000000  uid : 1000  pid : 2024  tag : ActivityManager
07-25 14:00:27.225    2024-2308/? W/ActivityManager﹕ mDVFSLock.acquire()
07-25 14:00:27.305    2024-2339/? D/WindowManager﹕ PhoneWindowManager: focusChangedLw
07-25 14:00:27.305    2024-2339/? D/KeyguardViewMediator﹕ setHidden false
07-25 14:00:27.346  16854-16854/org.example.whatstate D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-25 14:00:27.346  16854-16854/org.example.whatstate W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419ed2a0)
07-25 14:00:27.386  16854-16854/org.example.whatstate E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.whatstate/org.example.whatstate.GameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
            at org.example.whatstate.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.example.whatstate.GameFragment.<init>(GameFragment.java:47)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:577)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4695)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
            at org.example.whatstate.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 14:00:27.426    2024-2050/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
07-25 14:00:27.446  16955-16955/? I/dumpstate﹕ begin
```

fragment_game.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_high"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/menu_padding"
    tools:context=".WhatStateActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/menu_space"
        android:text="@string/guess_question"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idImageViewPic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="342dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.04"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#66FFFFFF"
        android:maxHeight="91dip"
        android:maxWidth="47dip"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/alabama" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ResponseText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/response_hint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="8pt">
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/guess_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/menu_button_margin"
        android:padding="@dimen/menu_button_padding"
        android:text="@string/continue_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Updated code** How do I find view by Id if the view was inflated elsewhere? (new to java):

```
public class GameFragment extends Fragment {

    private AlertDialog mDialog;
    private ImageView hImageViewPic;
    private Button iButton, gButton;

    private int currentImage = 0;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.alabama, R.drawable.alaska, R.drawable.arizona, R.drawable.california, R.drawable.done};

    final String[] capitals = {"montgomery", "juneau", "phoenix", "sacramento"};

    //final SharedPreferences highScorePreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //final SharedPreferences highScorePreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(0);
    //private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE = 0;
    //private SharedPreferences highScorePreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);

    //SharedPreferences highScorePreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //private SharedPreferences.Editor highScoreEdit = highScorePreferences.edit();



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false)

        return rootView;
    }


    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        hImageViewPic = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic);

        final TextView questionTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);

        iButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.guess_button);

        int resourceId = images[currentImage];
        String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
        //hImageViewPic.setImageResource(resourceId);
        hImageViewPic.setTag(name);
        final EditText responseField = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ResponseText);

        final MediaPlayer bubblePlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.bubble);
        final MediaPlayer swooshPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.swoosh);




        // Handle buttons here...
        final View guessButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.guess_button);
        guessButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            HighscoreManager hm = new HighscoreManager();
            int score = 0;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bubblePlayer.start();
                String response = responseField.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                String imageName = (String) hImageViewPic.getTag();
                String wrongTextAnnouncement = getString(R.string.wrong_text, imageName);


                Log.d("UT3", "response: " + response);
                Log.d("UT3", wrongTextAnnouncement);
                Log.d("UT3", "imageName: " + imageName);



                AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                final View customLayout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.capital_prompt, null);
                builder.setView(customLayout);

                if (imageName.equals(response)) {
                    Log.d("UT3", "right answer");
                    final EditText capitalInputField = (EditText) customLayout.findViewById(R.id.userInput);
                    //capitalInputField.setText("Capital name");
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.right_title);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.right_text);
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,
                                                    int i) {
                                    //nothing
                                    String capitalName = capitals[currentImage];
                                    String capitalResponse = capitalInputField.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                                    if (capitalResponse.equals(capitalName)){
                                        //add two points and move on to next picture
                                        Log.d("UT3", "got right capital name");
                                        score += 2;
                                        currentImage++;
                                        currentImage = currentImage % images.length;
                                        hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
                                        int resourceId = images[currentImage];
                                        String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
                                        //hImageViewPic.setImageResource(resourceId);
                                        hImageViewPic.setTag(name);
                                        swooshPlayer.start();
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Log.d("UT3", "got wrong capital name");
                                        currentImage++;
                                        currentImage = currentImage % images.length;
                                        hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
                                        int resourceId = images[currentImage];
                                        String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
                                        //hImageViewPic.setImageResource(resourceId);
                                        hImageViewPic.setTag(name);
                                        swooshPlayer.start();
                                    }
                                }
                            });


                    score += 10;
                    String scoreString = String.valueOf(score);
                    Log.d("UT3", "Score: " + scoreString);

                    //String capitalString = "Name its capital";

                    //iButton.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(iButton));

                } else {
                    Log.d("UT3", "wrong answer");
                    final View noCapitalLayout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.no_capital_prompt, null);
                    builder.setView(noCapitalLayout);
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.wrong_title);
                    //builder.setMessage(wrongTextAnnouncement);
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,
                                                    int i) {
                                    // nothing
                                }
                            });
                    //mDialog = builder.show();
                    currentImage++;
                    currentImage = currentImage % images.length;
                    hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
                    Log.d("UT3", "reached wrong answer");
                    int resourceId = images[currentImage];
                    String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
                    hImageViewPic.setImageResource(resourceId);
                    hImageViewPic.setTag(name);
                    swooshPlayer.start();
                }
                mDialog = builder.show();


                Log.d("UT3", "currentImage: " + currentImage);

                if (currentImage == 4) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder nameBuilder =
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    final View nameInputLayout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.name_prompt, null);
                    nameBuilder.setView(nameInputLayout);
                    final EditText nameInputField = (EditText) nameInputLayout.findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
                    nameBuilder.setTitle(R.string.right_title);
                    //nameBuilder.setMessage(R.string.right_text);
                    nameBuilder.setCancelable(false);


                    nameBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,
                                                    int i) {
                                    //nothing
                                    final String userName = nameInputField.getText().toString();
                                    hm.addScore(userName, score);
                                    Log.d("UT3", "userName: " + userName);

                                    String highScoreString = hm.getHighscoreString();
                                    Log.d("UT3", hm.getHighscoreString());
                                    score = 0;
                                    //highScoreEdit.putString("high_scores", highScoreString);
                                    //highScoreEdit.commit();
                                }
                            });
                    nameBuilder.show();

                }
            }


        });
    }

    View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button button)  {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setText("text now set.. ");

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Get rid of the about dialog if it's still up
        if (mDialog != null)
            mDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void restartGame() {
        initGame();
        initViews(getView());
    }

    public void initGame() {
        Log.d("UT3", "init game");
    }

    private void initViews(View rootView) {
        Log.d("UT3", "init views");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Try initialising your shared preferences inside onActivityCreated

Comment: @MarkKeen How should that look?

Comment: Move your on click listener into onActivityCreated. Only inflate and return your layout in onCreateView ...

Comment: post your fragment_game.xml

Comment: @MarkKeen I tried to do what I think you're saying. How can I find the view by id now if it was inflated elsewhere?

Comment: Declare an instance variable View 'rootView' rather than a local variable in onCreateView - initialise it in in your onCreateView, you can then access it from all methods in your Class.

Comment: infact do the same thing with all your shared prefs code - create instance variables, and implement what you want to happen in onActivityCreated

Answer (score 0):

You are crashing with a `NullPointerException` when creating the instance of `GameFragment`. Most of your commented-out code would trigger such a `NullPointerException`, as `getActivity()` will not work on a fragment until after `onAttach()` is called.